# Need to disable particular button in swipe cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell library to my project.

Certain situation I need to disable the particular button action of swipe cell.

I cannot find any property in their class file. If anyone crossed this, give me answer.

Here I have attaced my swipe options image:

[image]

**For ex**
: I want to disable the share button action.

Comment: can your share how you have added left and right buttons and on what action you want to disable particular button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your share button is in the leftButtonsArray. In the method:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state
{
   //case:left buttons opened      
   UIButton *shareButton = leftButtonsArray[theIndexOfTheShareButton];
    shareButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@karthikeyan You can hide the button for a particular row in tableview by the following code:

```
- (void)updateRightUtilityButtons:(NSArray *)rightUtilityButtons WithButtonWidth:(CGFloat) width {
_rightUtilityButtons = rightUtilityButtons;

[self.rightUtilityButtonsView updateUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons WithButtonWidth:width];

[self.rightUtilityButtonsView layoutIfNeeded];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Add/update this methods to `SWTableViewCell.m` class, where `rightUtilityButtons` is an array of buttons you need to display for the particular row.

In case if you want to disable just user interaction you can achieve while adding button into array, just disable user interaction for that button by `shareButton.userInteration = NO` and then add to array and then pass the array to the method defined above. By this you can be sure that button is disabled.

But please provide the sample code that you have worked so that can update your code directly.

In case if you still didn't get revert back I'll give you the working code directly here.

Comment: Cool, happy coding :)